# Meteor Template helpers: {{keyname}} showing blank

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

comment.html:

```
<template name="comment">
    <img src="{{photo}}"> //blank
    {{photo}} //blank
</template>
```

comments.js:

```
Template.comment.helpers({
    photo: function(){
        Meteor.call('getPhoto', function(error, result) {console.log(result);return result})
    }
});
```

server.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getPhoto: function () {
        return Meteor.user().services.vk.photo;
        }
});
```

Problem:
console.log returns right value, but {{photo}} is empty.
Question: why 'photo' is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [update]

I just realized what's the problem here.

`Meteor.call` is calling an async function, like an ajax call. So `Meteor.call('getPhoto')` would return undefined, the result is only retrievable in the callback

```
Meteor.call('getPhoto',function(err,result){console.log(result)});
```

With that in mind, you would need to come up with a way that captures that result in the callback. One solution is to use [`ReactiveVariable`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dependency_hasdependents):

You would first need to `$ meteor add reactive-var`

```
Template.comment.created = function (){
    var $this = this;
    $this.photo = new ReactiveVar("loading");
    Meteor.call('getPhoto', function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        $this.photo.set(result);
    });
}
```

And now define your helper to get the value;

```
   //this is optional
   Template.comment.helpers({
        photo: function(){ 
           return Template.instance().photo.get();
        }
    });
```

Another solution is to use [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session):

```
  //everything here is in the client
  Meteor.call('getPhoto', function(error, result){
    Session.set('thePhoto', result);
  });

  // use reactive Session variable in helper
  Template.comment.helpers({
    photo: function(){
      return Session.get('thePhoto');
    }
  });
```

The thing about using `Session` is that you are setting a global variable and if you have many comments and every comment would need to have an unique photo, `Session` is probably not the best way to do it.

---

You are calling the function `Meteor.call` when you are declaring the helpers.

```
Template.comment.helpers({
    photo: Meteor.call('getPhoto', function(error, result) {console.log(result);return result})

});
```

So what you are doing is equivalnt to:

```
var a = Meteor.call('getPhoto', function(error, result) {console.log(result);return result})
Template.comment.helpers({
        photo: a //a is just a value 
});
```

For [`.helpers`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) to work properly, you should be assigning a function to `photo` instead.

```
Template.comment.helpers({
    photo: function(){
       var r;
       Meteor.call('getPhoto', function(error, result) {r = result});
       return r;
    } 
});
```

> Under the hood, each helper starts a new Tracker.autorun. When its reactive dependencies change, the helper is rerun. Helpers depend on their data context, passed arguments and other reactive data sources accessed during execution. -From Meteor Doc

`.helpers` is supposed to be invoked as the very reason why you want to use `.helpers` is to enable [reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity) in your view. Thus what's inside `.helpers` need to be functions.

---

If you still don't get what I mean, here is simplified example:

```
var a = function(){ console.log("hey"); return 1}

var b = a();

var c = a; 

b(); //this would run into an error saying that b is a not a function

c(); //this would console.log "hey"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.I'm have modifyed comment.js file, but nothing changed ;(

Comment: @bartezr did it log any result? Is it possible that this is due to the missing `"` in your `<template name="comment>`?

Comment: @bartezr I have just figured out the issue; gimme a minute;

Comment: @bartezr just updated my post; tested; it would definitely work now.

Comment: Now it woking good. Thank you for helping and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @bartezr No worries. It's a good revision on Meteor Method for me too :)